# Plotting proportions of choices of each participant separately

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, proportions

I's like to find a quite efficient way to plot for each participant ($participant_num) the proportion of responses ($resp) every 10 trials ($trial, out of 200 trials per participant).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6owU.png)

When I did it for a subset of my sample (only 30 participants) I used a very rudimental code, for which I had first created a separate dataframe for each subject:

```
whichSubject<-6 # Which subject do want to analyse?
sData<-filter(banditData,subject==whichSubject)
```

and then I tried to get proportions for each 10 trials and put them in a separate column

```
sData$newcolumn <- NULL
sData$newcolumn1_10<- table(sData[1:10,]$resp)/length(sData[1:10,]$resp) 
sData$newcolumn11_20<- table(sData[11:20,]$resp)/length(sData[11:20,]$resp) 
sData$newcolumn21_30<- table(sData[21:30,]$resp)/length(sData[21:30,]$resp)
```

and so on for all the 200 trials and separately for each subject.. Then, I reshaped the dataframe as long and plotted it with the following script:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=rewardDF,aes(x=Trial,y=pHappy,colour=Bandit), linetype="dashed", size=1.03)+
  geom_point(data=longdf,aes(x=trial, y=resp_prop,colour=bandit,shape=bandit),size=3)+
  geom_line(data=longdf,aes(x=trial, y=resp_prop,colour=bandit),size=1)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=SymTypes)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette)+
  labs(col='bandit',y='p(choice)',x='trials')+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,200,by=10), limits=c(0,203), expand=(c(0,0)))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.1), limits=c(0,1.03), expand=(c(0.02,0)))+
  theme_bw()+
 ggsave(paste(c("data/S",whichSubject,"p(choice_absorangeblue).png"),collapse=""), scale=2,dpi = 300)
```

The output was something like this. Each dot represented how many times a participant selected left (resp=0) vs right (resp=1) in 10 trials (e.g., if the participant selected left 3 times out of 10 the dot for left, which corresponded to arm 1 in a task where you were asked to select between two arms, would be presented on the y axis at 0.3 and conversly the dot for right at 0.7)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5poVT.png)

However, now I have over 200 participants and it is definitely too time consuming using this approach!
I was thinking of using something to add `facet_grid(participant_num ~ .)+` to my ggplot code in order to code each participant separately without the need of sub selecting.. However, I haven't found a solution on how to plot the proportion of choices without having to calculate them separately. Do you have any tip on how I could do this within ggplot?

Many thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  By the way, posting data as an image is an excellent way to lose goodwill very quickly.

Comment: Please, share your data with `dput`